# ServiceNow table name for Asset

Tags: servicenow-rest-api

We are working on ServiceNow integration with our inhouse component, the need is to integrate Nuvolo Asset into the system. But from the documentation, it looks like Nuvolo is hosted in the ServiceNow platform. The ServiceNow has `Table` API but I couldn't find the table that belongs to the Assets in ServiceNow API. Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research found the Assets table can be accessed through the following APIs,

1. https://<INSTANCE_DOMAIN>/api/now/table/**alm_asset**?sysparm_offset=10&sysparm_limit=10
2. https://<INSTANCE_DOMAIN>/api/now/table/**cmdb_ci**?sysparm_offset=10&sysparm_limit=10